# Using SharedPreferences in a runnable

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I need to store some data in the `SharedPreferences` in a class derived from `Runnable`.

It seems like there is no way to get hands on it without a `context`. For example the following will need a context object which is not available to the Runnable instance.

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)
```

Is there any way to make it work in the Runnable or should I just go with the DB for all the preferences.

Comment: Have you tried one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875391/context-inside-a-runnable) suggestions?

Comment: Yeah. They suggest declaring the runnable inside an activity and use a local variable for the context. I prefer not to do that as I need my runnable to be reusable in other activities. 
Could I ask for a context in the runnable's constructor instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing the context in a field in your runnable and passing it as a constructor parameter? This way it could be reusable.

```
public class MyRunnable implemets Runnable{
    private Context context;

    public MyRunnable(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void run(){
        /...
    }
}
```