# Java Android - retrieve context inside runnable using a helper class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-context

I'm using Firebase to send messages to my Android app.
After this messages has been received (which works) - I want to open an `AlertDialog`.

From what I understood so far, receiving the message happens in a worker thread, so I need to hook into the main thread again. I build `Handler` with a `Runnable` for this. 
How can I retrieve my `MainActivity` context inside the runnable?
I looked up solutions like that [Context inside a Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875391/context-inside-a-runnable)

But the `MainActivity` is not the outer class when Firebase sends the messages.
Here is my setup

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.xhallix.passamessage;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.xhallix.passamessage.notifications.FireBaseMessagingServiceManager;
import com.example.xhallix.passamessage.notifications.MyApplication;
import com.example.xhallix.passamessage.notifications.NotificationManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CustomLog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FireBaseMessagingServiceManager fbMessagingService = new FireBaseMessagingServiceManager(this);

    }
}
```

**FireBaseMessagingServiceManager**

```
package com.example.xhallix.passamessage.notifications;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;


import com.example.xhallix.passamessage.MainActivity;
import com.example.xhallix.passamessage.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import android.os.Handler;

public class FireBaseMessagingServiceManager extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CustomLog";

    private Context context;

    public FireBaseMessagingServiceManager(){
        retrieveCurrentToken();
        // this is called when firebase is sending data
    }

    public FireBaseMessagingServiceManager(Context context){
        this.context = context; // this was just a test - this is not called when firebase sends the message again , so this.context will be null in onMessageReceive
    }


    /**
     * Get the Token of GoogleFirebase for that device
     */
    private void retrieveCurrentToken() {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get new Instance ID token
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, token);
                    }
                });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        createAlert();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
    }


    protected void createAlert() {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(**???**); // HOW TO RETRIEvE THE CONTEXT FROM MainActivity
                builder.setMessage(R.string.alert_dialog_msg);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_title);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Accepted Dialog");
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NOT Accepted Dialog");
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, a `Service` is a `Context`, but you can't really show a `Dialog` from a `Service` without some hacky fiddling. An alternative would be to start an `Activity` that uses a `Dialog` theme, but, in either case, suddenly popping something to the foreground isn't very user-friendly, especially if they're not even in your app. Have you considered showing a `Notification` instead?

Comment: @MikeM. yes I'm considering it right now because as you set, it seems very hacky.
I'm pretty new to android so I was not sure if that is really tricky or if I'm just doing a lot of things wrong here.

User friendly is not an issue here, it is just a prototype:)

Comment: Yeah, if this is just for testing/prototyping, I'd say use a `Notification`. It'll be much easier and straightforward to get that going, rather than try to implement one of the `Dialog` hacks. If you do really want a windowed UI, I suppose the `Dialog`-themed `Activity` isn't too involved, either (maybe even a little simpler, depending). It'd just be a separate `Activity` class, its layout, a `Theme.Dialog` in the manifest, and a `startActivity()` call. Whichever would be easier for ya.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I retrieve my MainActivity context inside the runnable?

You cannot get the MainActivity context because it has no relation to the service you're running it.

If you *really really* want to show the dialog directly in response to the push notification, you would explicitly launch a dialog themed Activity. Something like:

```
protected void createAlert() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DialogThemedActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
```

Comment: This is more like an alerting.
If we receive a message from push then something happens.
So I want the most disturbing thing to be displayed.
From what I see, notifications are far away from disturbing, what would you suggest?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Deliberately disturbing the user with a popup dialog regardless of what they are doing in the moment seems extremely aggressive and not something the average app should be doing.

A phone call or alarm, which is as "disturbing" as you can get, use notifications with the "urgent" importance: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#importance.  I'd hope that will work for you as well.

Comment: For the use case : Its some inner company app, which should alert if some system is going down